# .NET (VS2012) treats includes as XML - how to disable?

Tags: .net, xml, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to include certain features of my site as such:

```
  < !-- #Include virtual=".\includes\head.inc" -->
```

In this file, there's some style and javascript tags that I want to include on multiple pages, that look something like:
(in head.inc)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/style.css"> 
<script src="scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

However, I've been getting multiple errors that have not appeared before, relating to XML validation in head.inc. I don't want .inc files to be validated. How can I remove validation or fix this?

Comment: Why don't you just fix the files? I suspect it's validating them post-inclusion - have you tried just terminating your `link` tags?

Comment: @JonSkeet I can't really fix "XML document cannot contain multiple root level elements.", nor the variables <%=siteTitle %> (for example) that cause invalid XML names.

Comment: Okay - if you'd explained what the errors were, that would have been clearer. (I thought might just have been because the `link` tags were unclosed, for example.) Out of interest, do you still get the errors when you *don't* have the `.inc` files open? I've seen various errors in VS which only apply to open documents.

Comment: What is your doctype?  Is this XHTML or HTML ?

Comment: What are the "multiple error"?